# How to cluster standard errors of plm at different level rather than id or time?

Tags: r, plm

I run a panel regression by `plm`. `plm` only can cluster standard errors at "group" or "time" levels. But I want to cluster at the country level rather than group or time. (For my data, group is the firm level.)

I use the following code to cluster:
`summary(r, vcov = function(x) vcovHC(x, cluster = "group", method = "arellano"))`
But the options for `cluster` are only group and time. I want to cluster at country level.

Comment: please add your code, and a small sample of dataset

Comment: If you want to cluster at a level which does not serve as an index variable, plm is currently not capable of that. Maybe you have more luck with pacages `multiwayvcov`, `sandwich` and/or `clubSandwich`